# Dialogflow Suggestion Chip Responses in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, dialogflow-es

Just wondering if there is any way to get suggestion chip responses in Flutter from Dialogflow? I am working on a chat application and would like to add quick responses at the bottom of the screen to response to a Dialogflow chatbot.